# Web Api variable parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I've got a route defined in the WebApiConfig:

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "dav", routeTemplate:
 "api/values/{*file}", defaults: new { controller = "Values", action =
 "Get" });
```

The **{*file}** part of the route template defines that the number of parameters are variable. This is documentented on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#handling_a_variable_number_of_segments_in_a_url_pattern).

Got a controller with action Get:

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET")]
[ActionName("Get")]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(param string[] file)
{}
```

When run the uri `http://[mymachine]/api/values/1/1/2/3/` hits the method Get. Only the `file` array is empty.

Also tried the usual like:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string[] file)
```

And

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string file)
```

Both end in a 404.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried applying the `FromUri` attribute to the `file` parameter for any of those combinations?

Comment: It was a wild stab in the dark, and I didn't know which (if any) of your specs would actually work. You ought to post the working solution as an *answer* (rather than putting it at the bottom of the question) and mark it as accepted (you have to wait a bit to do this, IIRC). That way people know that you've solved the problem and don't need more help with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding attribute FromUri solves the problem.

Thanks to @Damien_The_Unbeliever.

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET")] [ActionName("Get")] 
public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri] string file)
```